# Is there any way to download a public DB to hard drive?

Tags: database, web-scraping

I'm a social science researcher, and I'm working with data from various public databases of NGO, government, etc. Let's assume that I've got no opportunity to ask the admins for the whole database. However, if I have enough patience, I'm able to download all the data one-by-one. But the size of the DB makes it almost impossible solving the problem with brute-force.

So, is there any way to download a public DB with all of it's components?

Here's an example:
http://www.trademap.org/tradestat/Country_SelProductCountry_TS.aspx

You can see the *Japanese Live animal import (USD) by the importing countries*. Is there a faster way to download all the data for every country and products as well than clicking them one-by-one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there exist software and web services for *scraping*. You can find them easily with Google - this is a programming, not a software recommendations site.

Beware that the use of automatic downloading tools may violate the terms of service, and get you into legal trouble. Also, websites may block your access when accessing them too fast.